# Can we call WCF service like wshttpbinding using jQuery?

Tags: json, wcf, wshttpbinding

Can we call WCF service with wshttpbinding using jquery to work with JSN format?
I know WCF REST could do but what about other bindings?

Comment: Yes you can, this link can help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/311908/Calling-WCF-service-exposed-with-different-binding

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do  WCF service with wshttpbinding using jquery to work with JSN format.